# Is it correct and natural to use the name of washing cycles on a washer as adverbs when you wash something?

Tags: adverbs

Is it correct and natural to use the name of washing cycles on a washer as adverbs when you wash something? For example:

> If you don't want to ruin your shirt, wash it **delicate**.
>
> If you want your laundry done as soon as possible, wash it **quick**.

If the sentences don't sound natural, what would a native English speaker say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, names of things (including names of washing cycles) are (by definition) nouns, and therefore cannot be used as adverbs.

The typical way to talk about using a particular setting for a washing machine, etc, is either something like "using the *(name)* setting", or sometimes more casually, "on *(name)*":

Also, when referring to names or descriptions of things which might be misconstrued as English words, it is generally best to put them in quotes, like so:

> If you don't want to ruin your shirt, wash it on "delicate".
>
> If you want your laundry done as soon as possible, wash it using the "quick" setting.